# Filebeat gives: object mapping for [error] tried to parse field [error] as object, but found a concrete value

Tags: elastic-stack, logstash-grok, filebeat

In elastic search i have created an ingest pipeline with the next grok pattern:

```
OK -%{DATA:label},%{INT:samples},%{BASE16FLOAT:average},%{BASE16FLOAT:min},%{BASE16FLOAT:max},%{BASE16FLOAT:p90},%{BASE16FLOAT:stddev},(?<error>([0-9].[0-9]*%)),
```

Simulating this with the next line:

```
OK - test,272,2275,593,14830,4581,1826.76,0.00%,.0,9.53,291717.4,30-04-2018 10:29:09
```

works perfect in kibana.

When i let filebeat indexing this file i get this error: `object mapping for [error] tried to parse field [error] as object, but found a concrete value` what goes wrong?

Comment: filebeat doesn't index anything, it ships data to logstash, elasticsearch etc, can you show your logstash config file for grok pattern please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Renaming the field error to run_error solves all the problems. It looks like the field error is reserved.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an mapping error in your elasticsearch index template. So check the value for error in your index template. 
Thats why it works with the grok matcher in kibana.

Anyway I would suggest the filter plugin csv, because it would parse it for you

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case, the cause of your problem is that in the same elastic index, your error property is found of type object and sometimes of type values, Elasticsearch does not allow this